# $L^1(P)$ random variable limit.

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables

for random variable $X$ in $L^1(P)$,

What is $\lim_{a\to \infty}a * P( |X| > a )$ ?

I think its value equals 0.

But I can't solve this problem.

I used markov's inequality But I can not understand it.

Comment: You have just to apply definitions. What does it mean that $X$ belongs to $L^1(P)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is a linear combination of characteristic functions, then 
$$a\mathbb P(|X|>a)\leqslant a\mathbb P(|X-Y|+|Y|>a)\leqslant a\mathbb P(\max\{|X-Y|, |Y|\}>a/2),$$
hence 
$$a\mathbb P(|X|>a)\leqslant a\mathbb P(|X-Y|>a/2)+a\mathbb P(|Y|>a/2).$$
Using Markov's inequality, we get
$$a\mathbb P(|X|>a)\leqslant 2\mathbb E|X-Y|+a\mathbb P(|Y|>a/2).$$
Since $Y$ is bounded, taking $\limsup_{a\to \infty}$, we obtain 
$$\limsup_{a\to \infty}a\mathbb P(|X|>a)\leqslant2\mathbb E|X-Y|$$
for each $Y$ a linear combination of characteristic functions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int |X|\,dP = \int_{|X| \le a} |X|\,dP + \int_{|X| > a} |X|\,dP$$
$$\int |X|\,dP \ge \int_{|X| \le a} |X|\,dP + aP(|X| > a)$$
$$\int |X|\,dP \ge \int |X|\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{|X| \le a\}}\,dP + aP(|X| > a)$$
Take limits as $a\to \infty$ and use the Dominated Convergence Theorem and the fact that a $L^1$ function is finite almost surely to conclude that the integral on the right limits to the integral on the left which is finite. This proves that $aP(|X|>a) \to 0$.